# Stream inflate wrapper?

Tags: php, http, compression, streaming

In PHP you can open a gzipped resource either like this:

```
$fp = fopen('compress.zlib://http://httpbin.org/gzip','rb')
```

or

```
$fp = gzopen('http://httpbin.org/gzip','rb')
```

How can I open a deflated resource? (such as http://httpbin.org/deflate)

N.B. I do **not** want to read the entire stream into memory so that I can run `gzinflate` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`stream_filter_append`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-filter-append.php) to apply an inflation filter on read.

```
$fp = fopen('http://httpbin.org/deflate','rb');
$params = array('level' => 6, 'window' => 15, 'memory' => 9);
stream_filter_append($fp, 'zlib.inflate', STREAM_FILTER_READ, $params);
print fread($fp,8192);
```

Comment: Looks like this works. Do those `$params` have any affect on a *read* though?

Comment: @Mark though not mentioned in the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/filters.compression.php), it looks like `window` is the only required parameter on read

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php), you can use the mode argument of `gzopen` to precise the compression mode.

Comment: I wasn't able to get `gzopen` to work with `deflate`. Do you have an example?